# Mailchimp validation conflicting with Joomla slider

Tags: javascript, joomla, mailchimp

I am trying to embedd Mailchimp subscribe form on my Joomla site. However, it is conflicting with my 'Gavick PhotoSlide GK2'. to prevent this happened, I need to use the 'Naked form(no css or javascript)'. This will tick the user over to the MailChimp signup page when subscribing. But is it possible to have the validation working inline and not conflicting with my slider? This is the code:

```
    <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css"><!--
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
--></style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup"><form action="http://thetrustsstadium.us4.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=xxx&amp;id=xxx" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span> </label> <input name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" type="email" /></div>
<div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-FNAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span> </label> <input name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME" type="text" /></div>
<div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span> </label> <input name="LNAME" class="required" id="mce-LNAME" type="text" /></div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"><input value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" type="submit" /></div>
</form></div>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var fnames = new Array();var ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';
try {
    var jqueryLoaded=jQuery;
    jqueryLoaded=true;
} catch(err) {
    var jqueryLoaded=false;
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if (!jqueryLoaded) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
    if (script.readyState && script.onload!==null){
        script.onreadystatechange= function () {
              if (this.readyState == 'complete') mce_preload_check();
        }    
    }
}



var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/jquery.form-n-validate.js';
head.appendChild(script);


var err_style = '';
try{
    err_style = mc_custom_error_style;
} catch(e){
    err_style = '#mc_embed_signup input.mce_inline_error{border-color:#6B0505;} #mc_embed_signup div.mce_inline_error{margin: 0 0 1em 0; padding: 5px 10px; background-color:#6B0505; font-weight: bold; z-index: 1; color:#fff;}';
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style= document.createElement('style');
style.type= 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet) {
  style.styleSheet.cssText = err_style;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err_style));
}
head.appendChild(style);
setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);

var mce_preload_checks = 0;
function mce_preload_check(){
    if (mce_preload_checks>40) return;
    mce_preload_checks++;
    try {
        var jqueryLoaded=jQuery;
    } catch(err) {
        setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);
        return;
    }
    try {
        var validatorLoaded=jQuery("#fake-form").validate({});
    } catch(err) {
        setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);
        return;
    }
    mce_init_form();
}
function mce_init_form(){
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
      var options = { errorClass: 'mce_inline_error', errorElement: 'div', onkeyup: function(){}, onfocusout:function(){}, onblur:function(){}  };
      var mce_validator = $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate(options);
      $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").unbind('submit');//remove the validator so we can get into beforeSubmit on the ajaxform, which then calls the validator
      options = { url: 'http://thetrustsstadium.us4.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=xxx&id=xxx&c=?', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    beforeSubmit: function(){
                        $('#mce_tmp_error_msg').remove();
                        $('.datefield','#mc_embed_signup').each(
                            function(){
                                var txt = 'filled';
                                var fields = new Array();
                                var i = 0;
                                $(':text', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        fields[i] = this;
                                        i++;
                                    });
                                $(':hidden', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        var bday = false;
                                        if (fields.length == 2){
                                            bday = true;
                                            fields[2] = {'value':1970};//trick birthdays into having years
                                        }
                                        if ( fields[0].value=='MM' && fields[1].value=='DD' && (fields[2].value=='YYYY' || (bday && fields[2].value==1970) ) ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else if ( fields[0].value=='' && fields[1].value=='' && (fields[2].value=='' || (bday && fields[2].value==1970) ) ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else {
                                            this.value = fields[0].value+'/'+fields[1].value+'/'+fields[2].value;
                                        }
                                    });
                            });
                        return mce_validator.form();
                    }, 
                    success: mce_success_cb
                };
      $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').ajaxForm(options);


    });
}
function mce_success_cb(resp){
    $('#mce-success-response').hide();
    $('#mce-error-response').hide();
    if (resp.result=="success"){
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(resp.msg);
        $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').each(function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    } else {
        var index = -1;
        var msg;
        try {
            var parts = resp.msg.split(' - ',2);
            if (parts[1]==undefined){
                msg = resp.msg;
            } else {
                i = parseInt(parts[0]);
                if (i.toString() == parts[0]){
                    index = parts[0];
                    msg = parts[1];
                } else {
                    index = -1;
                    msg = resp.msg;
                }
            }
        } catch(e){
            index = -1;
            msg = resp.msg;
        }
        try{
            if (index== -1){
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);            
            } else {
                err_id = 'mce_tmp_error_msg';
                html = '<div id="'+err_id+'" style="'+err_style+'" mce_style="'+err_style+'"> '+msg+'</div>';

                var input_id = '#mc_embed_signup';
                var f = $(input_id);
                if (ftypes[index]=='address'){
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-addr1';
                    f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else if (ftypes[index]=='date'){
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-month';
                    f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else {
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index];
                    f = $().parent(input_id).get(0);
                }
                if (f){
                    $(f).append(html);
                    $(input_id).focus();
                } else {
                    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
                }
            }
        } catch(e){
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
        }
    }
}
// --></script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: There is a bug in the mailchimp-provided jquery.form-n-validate.js file that breaks certain jQuery.ajax calls that try to pass the URL as the first parameter.  I've contacted their support team this week and I encourage you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible, but there's no way to tell with just the code you posted. We'll need a link to a test page so we can take a look at the whole thing and see where the conflicts are. Before I spent a bunch of time messing with it though, I would try this component -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/mailing-a-newsletter-bridges/13602

It comes with a sign up module and it seems to integrate pretty well with most 3rd party javascript. Try it before you do anything else, it may just work.

Otherwise you will likely have to rewrite the validation or switch to server side validation in order to fix the conflict.

Comment: Hi Brent, I have tried joomlamailer before. I dropped it because it takes a long time to add a new user. I have over 1,3000 subscriber on my site. Then I am trying the embeded form from http://mailchimp.com

Comment: What do you mean by slow to add new user? Do yo mean when a user submits the form on the front end? If your subscribers are already in mailchimp you shouldn't have to do anything, they are already there.

Comment: Hi Brent, I mean it takes a long time for new subscriber to submit. It is just showing 'adding...' for a long time. And same thing happened for validation.

Comment: Does it eventually work? That's odd that you would have issues because the module uses basically the same code to make it work.